# Picker Custom Control in Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin

I am new to Xamarin and I never worked on Custom Control. Can someone show me how to create a custom control using Picker with the `SelectedIndexChanged` property exposed? Thank You so much

Comment: You should be able to do with simple Binding to a public get/set property such as following MVVM pattern.  When the index changes, the SETTER is called and you can do whatever from that.  Do you have other C# experience and using MVVM pattern, and data binding?

Comment: Have you looked at the samples and docs on custom controls?  Do you know how to create custom C# events?  What is "custom" about this control that is different from a basic picker?